# Input text not being cleared out

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to clear an input text after saving some data but it just doesn't work. This is what I've tried so far (what it's in comments too):

Thanks in advance for any help!

**HTML:**

```
<div id="add-tag">
    <h3>Add new tag</h3>
    <form name="addTagForm">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="newTag" ng-change="onChangeTag()">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addTag(newTag)">Add Tag</button>  
    </form>             
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
//$scope.master = {};

// Reset scope
$scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.newTag = "";
    //$scope.newTag = angular.copy($scope.master);
};


$scope.addTag = function(tag) {

    // Save some data (this works fine) 
    // ....

    // Reset input field
    $scope.reset();     
};
```

**UPDATE:**

My ng-controller was set to the parent template (I'm using ui.router). Just added it to the child template and it indeed worked.

```
<div id="add-tag" ng-controller="FormController">
    <h3>Add new tag</h3>
    <form name="addTagForm">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="newTag" ng-change="onChangeTag()">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addTag(newTag)">Add Tag</button>  
    </form>             
</div>
```

Comment: Could you give a working example of it.Since your code is resetting the text box.

Comment: This code must work fine. see if there is other code causing problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am new in angularjs but after trying some thing i got some sort of solution for you. You can check [this bin](http://jsbin.com/gifivuva/1/edit). I have just added a controller :-

```
function test_c($scope){

$scope.reset = function() {
$scope.newTag = "";
//$scope.newTag = angular.copy($scope.master);
};

$scope.addTag = function(tag) {

// Save some data (this works fine) 
// ....

// Reset input field
$scope.reset();     
};}
```

Look at the html part:-

```
<body ng-app>
  <div id="add-tag" ng-controller="test_c">
    <h3>Add new tag</h3>
    <form name="addTagForm">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="newTag" ng-change="onChangeTag()">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addTag(newTag)">Add Tag</button>  
    </form>             
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Bik! I was already using a Controller, but also ui.router using templates. The ng-controller was set to the parent template. Just added it to my template and it worked!